# SED command to replace a complex PHP string at the beginning of an existing PHP file

Tags: php, bash, sed

I decided to install ZB Block on several PHP based websites I am seeing attacks on.  All websites are running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / Apache 2.4 / PHP 5.5.9

The ZB Block script call needs to be inserted at the beginning of each .php file. In the interest of  automating the string replacement across all .php files on multiple websites I made a sed statement to perform the replacement on the first occurrence of

```
sed '#s:<?php:<?php require('/var/www/html-mydomain.tld/zbblock/zbblock.php'); ?><?php#’ First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample.php > First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample.tmp && mv First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample.tmp First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample-NEW.php
```

Running the sed statement gave the following results:
 1 File named First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample-NEW.php is made, GOOD
 2 The desired string replacement is not made. BAD

```
 # ls -l
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39 Feb 17 15:40 First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample-NEW.php
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39 Feb 17 15:13 First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample.php

 # nano First-Occurence-Replacement-Sample-NEW.php

 Line 1 <?php <<< string wasn’t replaced as desired.
 Line 2 /***************************************************************************
 Line 3 <?php <<< This second occurrence should never be replaced
 Line 4 ?> ?>
```

Desired sed statement behavior

Sample file before string replacement

```
 Line 1 <?php
 Line 2 /***************************************************************************
 Line 3 <?php
 Line 4 ?>
```

Sample file after string replacement

```
 Line 1 <?php require('/var/www/html-mydomain.tld/zbblock/zbblock.php'); ?><?php
 Line 2 /***************************************************************************
 Line 3 <?php <<< This second occurrence should never be replaced
 Line 4 ?> ?>
```

How does the sed statement need to be changed to achieve the desired replacement ?

After I can get help getting this sed statement working I want to put it in a script to run the replacements on an entire directory full of .php files like so:

Create script file:
 # nano zbblock-string-insertion.bash

```
 #! /bin/bash
 for f in *.php
 do
 echo "Converting $f"
 sed '#s:<?php:<?php require('/var/www/html-mydomain.tld/zbblock/zbblock.php'); ?><?php#’ $f > $f.tmp && mv $f.tmp $f
 done
```

Save file zbblock-string-insertion.bash , make it executable, and run it!

Kenavoz,
It works, thanks! Your a genius ! Don't let your in-laws tell you any different.

To recurse directories modify the command line provided by Kenavox to:

```
find -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -I.........
```

Now. the command does recursive replacement.

Comment: Makes not much sense. Better use php.ini or use auto_prepend_file. But generally I recommend alternatives as ZB Block is not actively developed anymore, does not support IPv6 and has many outdated (and wrong) signatures.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Which 3rd party solution do you recommend / use ?

Comment: I use NinjaFirewall from nintechnet.com on more than 100 websites at the moment. There is a new version coming soon, which is much better, the current version is still very strong, fast, reliable and easy to maîntain. Also I use filemonitoring solutions, CIDR blocklists and other things, all linked on https://websectools.com phpMussel and IDRAM are created by Maikuolan (Caleb), who is also a member of the SpambotSecurity forum. CIDRAM, the referral-spam-blacklist and NinjaFirewall are a full and secure replacement for ZB Block.

Comment: I'm gonna look into al that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help:

```
find . -name *.php -type f -exec sed -i "1 s~<?php~<?php require('/var/www/html-mydomain.tld/zbblock/zbblock.php'); ?>&~" {} \;
```

It finds all php files in or under the current dir and applies the sed command to each.

The sed command adds the php require command to the first occurrence in the first line of the file.

Comment: It works, thanks!
Your a genius !  Don't let your in-laws tell you any different.

Comment: Any idea how to make that find recursive ?

Comment: I've updated the command, now finds all php files recursively from current directory (`find . -name '*.php'`)